# Merge SAS Datasets

Tags: sas

I have two datasets.

DATASET: A

```
EE_ID     PRJ_CD  
100055    406
100055    475
100055    492
300028    475
```

DATASET: B

```
EE_ID     SSN               EMP_CD 
100055    0100055           E
300028    0300028           E
```

I have sorted & merged the above two datasets by EE_ID.

```
DATA FINAL;                  
   MERGE A B;                  
   BY EE_ID;                

   IF A THEN OUTPUT;                     
RUN;
```

Output:

```
EE_ID           PRJ_CD   SSN          EMP_CD
100055          475                        
100055          492                        
100055          406      0100055      E    
300028          475      0300028      E
```

`SSN` and `EMP_CD` is getting populated for only one row and the remaining two rows are empty for the `EE_ID = 100055`.

My expectation is :-

```
EE_ID           PRJ_CD   SSN         EMP_CD                                                
100055          475      0100055      E            
100055          492      0100055      E            
100055          406      0100055      E    
300028          475      0300028      E
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `IF A THEN OUTPUT;`?? `A` will be empty all the time and using this code you should not have results at all. Please also format text in your problem. It is not so hard.

Answer (score 1):

As fl0r3k mentioned above, the code you supplied wouldn't work, you would get no results.

Once you have sorted `A` and `B` by `EE_ID` you could use the following code:

```
data final;
 merge a b;
  by ee_id;
  run;
```

I'm not sure what your intent is with `IF A THEN OUTPUT;` If you have more records in B than displayed in your example and only want to include records in A then try

```
data final;
 merge a (in=a) b;
  by ee_id;
  if a ;
  run;
```

Based on your example A and B datasets above you will get the same results from use of either code.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine for your example data.

```
data a;
  input ee_id prj_cd ;
cards;
100055    406
100055    475
100055    492
300028    475 
;

data b ;
  input ee_id ssn emp_cd $;
cards;
100055    0100055           E
300028    0300028           E 
;

data want;
  merge a(in=in1) b ;
  by ee_id;
  if in1;
run;
```

Your real data probably already has SSN and EMP_CD on the A dataset. You can drop them in the merge statement, if you cannot remove them earlier in the process.

```
data want;
  merge a(in=in1 drop=ssn emp_cd) b ;
  by ee_id;
  if in1;
run;
```